# For each for tooltip change placement on click of another button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two buttons, click one and it changed the direction of the Bootstrap tooltip left and then the other does the opposite. I can only manage to get it to work on the first instance of the element with the tooltip and not the others. I'm missing a for each function but I can't figure it out at all.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/veqac/1/edit?html,js,output**

### Q: get all instances, not just the first instance, of the tooltip to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tippy = $('.wrapper [data-hover="tooltip"]');

      tippy.tooltip({
         trigger: 'hover',
         container: 'body'
      });

  $('.change-dir-left').click(function (e) {
   tippy.data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'left';
   e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.change-dir-right').click(function (e) {
   tippy.data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
   e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default change-dir-left">Change Tooltip Direction Left </a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default change-dir-right">Change Tooltip Direction Right </a>
<hr>
<div class="wrapper">
   <button type="button" class="btn center-block btn-default" data-hover="tooltip" title="Me">Tooltip</button> <br>  <button type="button" class="btn center-block btn-default" data-hover="tooltip" title="Me">Tooltip</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to call your elements by class rather than by data-hover

Comment: @CodeGodie - that is not accurate. Most of Bootstrap doesn't use classes, they use data-toggle or whatever so they get multiple uses from a single script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.change-dir-left').click(function (e) {
    tippy.each(function(){
        $(this).data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'left';
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.change-dir-right').click(function (e) {
    tippy.each(function(){
        $(this).data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @Christina glad to hear. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tippy = $('.wrapper [data-hover="tooltip"]');

      tippy.tooltip({
         trigger: 'hover',
         container: 'body'
      });

  $('.change-dir-left').click(function (e) {
    $('.a').each(function(i)
    {
 $(this).data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'left';
    });
   e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.change-dir-right').click(function (e) {
     $('.a').each(function(i)
    {
   $(this).data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
     });
   e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

And I have added a class `a`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="a btn center-block btn-default" data-hover="tooltip" title="Me">Tooltip</button> <br>  <button type="button" class="a btn center-block btn-default" data-hover="tooltip" title="Me">Tooltip</button>
  </div>
```